# How do i set a (open_)basedir with php using fastcgi/nginx?

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

Essentially i found out you can limit the folders each user has access to by using php's basedir/open_basedir.

I'd like to have each php only access its own files. So i wrote

```
fastcgi_param  open_basedir       $document_root;
```

in hopes that it would work. It didnt. I googled and only found results saying you cant do it via fastcgi or nginx.

Is this true or can i not do it?

PS: I -do- spawn php as its own user (rather then www-data) so it doesnt wreak havoc on my nonphp websites. But i still like to prevent one php script on a php site from accessing other directories (if i have a wordpress install on yourface.com its pretty obvious a valid php path is `/var/www/yourface/<wordpress scripts>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent versions of php, ini values can be set over fastcgi.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215120/set-php-include-path-from-nginx for details.

Comment: This doesnt appear to work. I'm using version 5.3.3. The current stable is 5.3

Comment: The comments on the php bug say that it should be working in 5.3.3.  What's the line you added to nginx.conf?  Are you using fpm?

Comment: ah ha. I was using php-fastcgi instead of fpm. I always thought fpm is for apache. So my config line was correct! (which i got from your answer link). Thanks!